# I'm getting error code 0x01 when socks5 is trying to connect to an ip address. Client socks5 in c++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm getting an error code 0x01 when the socket is trying to make the connection. For some reason it fails and I don't know why. SOCKS v5 connect failed, error: 0x01

```
        #include <winsock2.h>
        #include <windows.h>
        #include <ws2tcpip.h>
        #include <iphlpapi.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <inaddr.h>


        #include <pshpack1.h>
        struct socks5_ident_req
        {
            unsigned char Version;
            unsigned char NumberOfMethods;
            unsigned char Methods[256];
        };

        struct socks5_ident_resp
        {
            unsigned char Version;
            unsigned char Method;
        };

        struct socks5_req
        {
            unsigned char Version;
            unsigned char Cmd;
            unsigned char Reserved;
            unsigned char AddrType;
            union {
                in_addr IPv4;
                in6_addr IPv6;
                struct {
                    unsigned char DomainLen;
                    char Domain[256];
                };
            } DestAddr;
            unsigned short DestPort;
        };

        struct socks5_resp
        {
            unsigned char Version;
            unsigned char Reply;
            unsigned char Reserved;
            unsigned char AddrType;
            union {
                in_addr IPv4;
                in6_addr IPv6;
                struct {
                    unsigned char DomainLen;
                    char Domain[256];
                };
            } BindAddr;
            unsigned short BindPort;
        };
        #include <poppack.h>

        bool sendData(SOCKET fd, void *data, int len)
        {
            char *ptr = (char *) data;

            while (len > 0)
            {
                int sent = send(fd, ptr, len, 0);
                if (sent <= 0)
                {
                    printf("send() error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                    return false;
                }
                ptr += sent;
                len -= sent;
            }

            return true;
        }

        int recvData(SOCKET fd, void *data, int len, bool disconnectOk = false)
        {
            char *ptr = (char *) data;
            int total = 0;

            while (len > 0)
            {
                int recvd = recv(fd, ptr, len, 0);
                if (recvd < 0)
                {
                    printf("recv() error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                    return -1;
                }
                if (recvd == 0)
                {
                    if (disconnectOk)
                        break;
                    printf("disconnected");
                    return -1;
                }
                ptr += recvd;
                len -= recvd;
                total -= recvd;
            }

            return total;
        }

        bool socksLogin(SOCKET fd)
        {
            socks5_ident_req req;
            socks5_ident_resp resp;

            req.Version = 5;
            req.NumberOfMethods = 1;
            req.Methods[0] = 0x00;
            // add other methods as needed...

            if (!sendData(fd, &req, 2+req.NumberOfMethods))
                return false;

            if (recvData(fd, &resp, sizeof(resp)) == -1)
                return false;

            if (resp.Version != 5)
            {
                printf("SOCKS v5 identification failed");
                return false;
            }

            if (resp.Method == 0xFF)
            {
                printf("SOCKS v5 authentication failed");
                return false;
            }

            /*
            if (resp.Method != 0x00)
            {
                // authenticate as needed...
            }
            */

            return true;
        }

        bool socksRequest(SOCKET fd, const socks5_req &req, socks5_resp &resp)
        {
            memset(&resp, 0, sizeof(resp));

            if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&req, 4))
                return false;

            switch (req.AddrType)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&(req.DestAddr.IPv4), sizeof(in_addr)))
                        return false;

                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&(req.DestAddr.DomainLen), 1))
                        return false;

                    if (!sendData(fd, (void*)req.DestAddr.Domain, req.DestAddr.DomainLen))
                        return false;

                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&(req.DestAddr.IPv6), sizeof(in6_addr)))
                        return false;

                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    printf("SOCKS 5 requesting unknown address type");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            unsigned short port = htons(req.DestPort);
            if (!sendData(fd, &port, 2))
                return false;

            if (recvData(fd, &resp, 4) == -1)
                return false;

            switch (resp.AddrType)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    if (recvData(fd, &(resp.BindAddr.IPv4), sizeof(in_addr)) == -1)
                        return false;

                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    if (recvData(fd, &(resp.BindAddr.DomainLen), 1) == -1)
                        return false;

                    if (recvData(fd, resp.BindAddr.Domain, resp.BindAddr.DomainLen) == -1)
                        return false;

                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    if (recvData(fd, &(resp.BindAddr.IPv6), sizeof(in6_addr)) == -1)
                        return false;

                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    printf("SOCKS 5 bound to unknown address type");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (recvData(fd, &port, 2, 0) == -1)
                return false;

            resp.BindPort = ntohs(port);

            return true;
        }

        bool socksConnect(SOCKET fd, const in_addr &dest, unsigned short port)
        {
            socks5_req req;
            socks5_resp resp;

            req.Version = 5;
            req.Cmd = 1;
            req.Reserved = 0;
            req.AddrType = 1;
            req.DestAddr.IPv4 = dest;
            req.DestPort = port;

            if (!socksRequest(fd, req, resp))
                return false;

            if (resp.Reply != 0x00)
            {
                printf("SOCKS v5 connect failed, error: 0x%02X", resp.Reply);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        int main() {
            WSADATA wsaData;
            int Result;
            const char szHost[] = "www.google.com";
            //initalize winsock
            Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
            if (Result != 0) {
                printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", Result);
                return 1;
            }

            //create socket
            SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (sock < 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            SOCKADDR_IN sin;
            ZeroMemory(&sin, sizeof(sin));
            sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sin.sin_port = htons(9150);
            sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

            //connect to server
            if (connect(sock, (const sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) != 0) {
                printf("Failed1");
                return 1;
            }

            if (!socksLogin(sock)) {
                printf("Failed2");
                return 1;
            }
            struct in_addr addr;
            addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("151.101.1.140");
            if (!socksConnect(sock, addr, 80)) {
                printf("Failed!3");
            return 1;
            }

            printf("Success!");

            return 0;
        }
```

I'm getting an error code 0x01 when the socket is trying to make the connection. For some reason it fails and I don't know why. SOCKS v5 connect failed, error: 0x01

Comment: `req.DestPort = port;` is suspicious. I guess you should also use `htons` in this line to make the correct order bytes, as it is done while filling `sockaddr_in` struct.

Comment: I already have `unsigned short port = htons(req.DestPort);` . I also added htons on the line you told me but I'm still getting error code 0x01 after it's done authenticating and tries to connect to the ip. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Nevermind I solved it myself. I had to change `if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&(req.DestAddr.IPv4), sizeof(in_addr)))` to`if (!sendData(fd, (void*)&(req.DestAddr.IPv4.S_un.S_addr), sizeof(in_addr)))` . Thanks for the help @rafix07 :)